# How to use OData's Display.FormattedValue

Tags: odata

I've been trying to use the ability of OData's `Display.FormattedValue`, but I cannot find any good source on how to implement it. I've searched the code in the entire OData organization (which yields no code for `formattedvalue`, `displayablevalue`).

I've read many links, including the following:

- http://odata.github.io/WebApi/04-19-odataIncludeAnnotations/
- https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/75
- https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-787

But I still don't understand how to implement it.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly easy. One merely has to follow [the CustomODataFormatter example](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/CustomODataFormatter). The AnnotatingEntitySerializer found in the [CustomODataSerializerProvider code](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/WebApiCore/CustomODataFormatter/Extensions/CustomODataSerializerProvider.cs) does all the work of adding an annotation, in this case a score. This code is easily adjusted to create something resembling the OData.FormattedValue.

```
// A custom entity serializer that adds the score annotation to document entries.
public class AnnotatingEntitySerializer : ODataResourceSerializer
{
    public AnnotatingEntitySerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ODataResource CreateResource(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, ResourceContext resourceContext)
    {
        ODataResource entry = base.CreateResource(selectExpandNode, resourceContext);

        Document document = resourceContext.ResourceInstance as Document;
        if (entry != null && document != null)
        {
            // annotate the document with the score.
            entry.InstanceAnnotations.Add(new ODataInstanceAnnotation("org.northwind.search.score", new ODataPrimitiveValue(document.Score)));
        }

        return entry;
    }
}
```